# Instagram Search for a tag within particular date range

Tags: date, search, tags, instagram

I am looking to retrieve results from instagram for a particular tag **mytag** , I tried using this API call,

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent

but it only returned 33 results even though there are more results. This question can be considered an extension to this question: [How To Search Instagram via API Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634881/how-to-search-instagram-via-api-query)

What is the way to return instagram results for a particular tag within a date range?
This may be done through the min_tag_id and max_tag_id which. Not sure how to convert my date time to min_tag_id or max_tag_id?

Answer (score 5):

call the API with `max_tag_id` and `min_tag_id` like this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&max_tag_id=1378677250000000&min_tag_id=1375998850000000
```

max_tag_id and min_tag_id is `epoch_time + "000000"`

you still only get 20 per API call, use pagination to get all

> Update: Instagram changed the `tag_id`, so date filter cannot be done
>   this way. Login on http://gramfeed.com and search for a hashtag and
>   you can do date/time filter, its a different hack implementation.

Comment: Your definition of max and min tag id may not be true, I received this value from the API, "min_tag_id": "1410204473722500" This does not have the zeroes at the end you suggested.

Comment: 1410204473 is epoch time, the 6 digit can be ignored, I have implemented in gramfeed.com, u can search tag and filter by time, works pretty good

Comment: has that changed or something? im seeing an id like "1098750435004692292_2135229268." after the underscore is clearly the username id but before it does not appear to be epoch time

Comment: @krisrak Is this still valid? Saw you are using for gramfeed a frontend filter for datetime ranges.

Comment: This is not valid anymore, instagram changed the `tag_id`. I'm doing a different api date filter and getting tag_id and using that for max_tag_id, its not perfect but works