# Finding Instagram tag_id of a post to search by date range

Tags: instagram

I'm building a JavaScript app that returns Instagram posts with a given tag, using the `tags/tag-name/media/recent` endpoint. I'm trying to add in functionality to search by date range. Min/max_timestamp works for the Users API, but the Tag API only accepts min/max_tag_id. Following the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729166/instagram-search-for-a-tag-within-particular-date-range#comment57499475_25733770), I am trying to search the Users API with my dates of interest. The idea is to get post id's that correspond with my dates, then plug those id's into the min/max_tag_id in the Tag API.

However, the post id returned from the Users API (ie 9999999999999999999_9999999) appears to be a different format than what min/max_tag_id is looking for, confirmed by a Tag API paging response (131 character string of characters, numbers, underscores and hyphens).

Is there any way I can find a tag_id using a date-based search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `max_tag_id` and `min_tag_id` value is not `media_id` anymore after the June 1, 2016 API changes.

When API was first launched, the `max_tag_id` and `min_tag_id` was taking epoch timestamp value, then it was changed to actual `media_id` and now it looks like it is some cryptic value that is not easy to decode.

I was supporting date/time search for all feeds before, but now it is not possible for tag media feed. I have implemented date/time search in https://picodash.com for all feeds except tag media

Comment: Thanks for the overview. I'll consider having an option to search for tags in the last week or month. That way I can page through the recent results until I find media that is before the specified date.

Comment: if its a very popular hashtag then u may have to page thru a lot before u get to last week/month, may become an issue with API limits